# Buck converter simulation issues

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I am trying to use a buck converter to step down a 48v to 33v. The confusing part is that I am trying to simulate it using LTspice and I can’t figure what how to control the nmos with pulse width modulation . Do I need a control circuit for the purpose of simulation or how can I go about it .

Answer (score 0):

If you simulate a synchronous buck converter then the two switches (yes, there are two in a synchronous buck converter) are wired like this: -

[image]

Picture above from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195662/buck-converters-no-load-condition/195663#195663).

If SW1 is on then SW2 is off and vice versa. This means that the average output voltage is the input supply voltage (12 volts in the example above) * duty cycle. In the picture above the duty cycle (as a fraction) is: -

$$\dfrac{5}{12} = 41.667 \text{ %} $$

And that leads to an average output voltage of 5 volts. The inductor and capacitor on the output smooth the PWM waveform to a (hopefully) low ripple DC voltage of 5 volts.

> *I can’t figure what how to control the nmos with pulse width
>   modulation*

Use a voltage generator source (set as a square wave of the appropriate duty cycle) to drive the MOSFETs (or switches) just to get a feel for it. Following that, you can develop a PMW signal source based on an analogue input but make sure you get the basics right first.

This usually involves a comparator fed with a reference triangle wave like this: -

[image]

Circuit from [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3201.html).

But you can use an LTSpice voltage source set to produce a triangle wave if you wanted and just use the comparator indicated by U1c in the above.